# Will StyleCopAnalyzers causing performance or security issue?

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

I am currently including StyleCop.Analyzers package to do code analysis. It seems to me the package will leverage .net compiler to do the work thus it's compile time overhead. Are there any other considerations I need to be aware?
Here are my current settings on the project.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Identity.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>custom.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Identity.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>custom.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>   
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    .......
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It's static code analysis - it won't affect runtime performance.

Comment: *StyleCop* yeah nah. Been there done that bought the tshirt and very happy i don't use it anymore. As for your question, no it wont affect run time performance, everything is a security risk, but it would be minimal, and yes it will slow down your IDE. However most of all, it will seriously bug you, and future developers will hate you for it if you enforce too many things

Comment: my team mate start hate me due to the strict rules...